# Find if a string contains a phrase from a list in python

Tags: python, string, search

I need to find if a string contains a phrase from a list, and print it.

For example:

```
my_phrases = ['Hello world', 'apple', 'orange', 'red car']

my_string = 'I am driving a red car'
```

The result should hopefully say that "a phrase or word has been found" and is "red car"

I found a way to do that with single words in a very clever way (found on another discussion):

```
def words_in_string(word_list, my_string):
   return set(word_list).intersection(my_string.split())
```

So

```
if words_in_string(word_list,my_string):
           print('a word has been found ')
for word in words_in_string(word_list,my_string):
           print(word)
```

it works if word_list is a list of single words, but it doesn't if I try to use phrases.

Comment: If you need to check for whole words, you will need  a regex, see [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/1t6v7d).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this solve the issue:

```
my_phrases = ['Hello world', 'apple', 'orange', 'red car']

my_string = 'I am driving a red car'


for phrase in my_phrases:
    if phrase in my_string:
        print(phrase)
```